# R select names from a list using logical vector

Tags: r, list, vector

Suppose I have my `list` with names and its component and I want to get those names which have its components in other vector:

that is my list **neighbors**

```
neighbors[[1]]
 [1] "CNBP"                  "IGF2BP1"               "RPL3|OK/SW-cl.32"     
 [4] "HNRNPC"                "PURA|hCG_45299"        "RPS3A"                
         "Cnbp"                  "Mis12|DN-393H17.5"    
neighbors[[2]]
[1] "NIN"                "PRKACA"             "AURKA|RP5-1167H4.6"
[4] "GSK3B"              "AMOT"               "UBC"
```

and my vector of interest
    **mtop**

```
[1] "TUBA1A"                "DNAJB1"                "MME"                  
[4] "PRKCB"                 "PARK2|KB-152G3.1"      "UBC"
```

My idea for example is return the name of `neighbors[2]`, which have in common UBC

Any ideas??

Comment: Providing a fully reproducible example would help greatly (for example, including `dput(neighbors)` and `dput(mtop)` in your post). Also helpful would be a concrete example of the output you expect (ideally an R object).

Answer (score 2):

First off, your data. Your output appears sonewhat strange. If this is not what you have, consider using `dput` to dump these variables in a reproducible way.

```
mtop <- c("TUBA1A", "DNAJB1", "MME",
          "PRKCB", "PARK2|KB-152G3.1", "UBC")
neighbors <- list(c("CNBP", "IGF2BP1", "RPL3|OK/SW-cl.32",
                    "HNRNPC", "PURA|hCG_45299", "RPS3A",
                    "Cnbp", "Mis12|DN-393H17.5"),
                  c("NIN", "PRKACA", "AURKA|RP5-1167H4.6",
                    "GSK3B", "AMOT", "UBC"))
```

To select those elements of list `neighbors` which have at least one vector element in common with `mtop`, you can use this command:

```
matching <- sapply(neighbors, function(l) length(intersect(mtop, l)) > 0)
print(neighbors[matching])
```

This will print `neighbors[2]`, as it has `"UBC"` in common with `mtop`. It does this via the logical vector `matching`. Which seems to be what your question asked.

If you want to take position into account, i.e. only select `neighbors[2]` because `"UBC"` is in position 6 in both vectors, then you should use this command:

```
matching <- sapply(neighbors, function(l) any(l == mtop))
```

However, this will create a warning, as `neighbors[[1]]` is longer than `mtop`.

If you want the names common to both your data structures, you can use this code:

```
intersect(unlist(neighbors), mtop)
```

If you need something else, you have to be more specific in your question, i.e. give an explicit example of what the output should look like, and cover all the possible input configurations that might lead to structurally different output.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
l<- lapply(neighbours,function(x)x[x %in% mtop])
```

This will return the list where each list element will have the elements which are in the vector `mtop`.

Now select only those elements which have non-zero length:

```
names(l)[sapply(l,length)>0]
```

You can combine these into one line:

```
names(neighbours)[sapply(neighbours,function(x)Reduce("|",mtop %in% x))]
```

Comment: Yes you should have. You want only the match of which elements of the list has the desired names?